# Turn custom link to formula field

Tags: salesforce, sfdc

I have created a custom link for a custom object and it works. But it's not controlled by FLS so I have to move to Formula field.

What should I do to turn it to a formula field?

Here's my custom link codes:
https://sanofi-pharmachina--dev1.cs5.my salesforce.com/a0C?rlid=01I7F000002B91V&id={Account_Plan_vod__r.Account.ID!}

a0C is object code
01I7F000002B91V is object ID
{Account_Plan_vod__r.Account.ID!}

How should I turn this to a formula field with proper codes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The HYPERLINK formula, this should work. It shows your link as a clickable url on the detail page of a record:

HYPERLINK("/a0C?rlid=01I7F000002B91V&id=" & Account_Plan_vod__r.Account.ID,"Link Text here")